# Determine derivative of polynomial from graph on a multiple choice question

Tags: polynomials

On a multiple choice question I need to determine which of the following graphs:

[Multiple choice graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saQQA.png)

[image]

When derivated, yields:

[The graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAyaj.png)

[image]

Is there a general, fastest way to solve this kind of questions?

My math is rusty and I'm trying to catch up.

Comment: To start, I'd encourage you to think about the ranges for which the slope is positive, negative, and zero, as well as how the slopes themselves change in these regions.

Comment: In this case, the graph of the derivative shows that it has two zeros, at both of which it changes sign.  The original function must therefore have turning points at precisely those two points and nowhere else.  This alone is enough to rule out all but one of the multiple choice graphs. Even so, I'd suggest you follow [cmk's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/671645/cmk) advice as way of confirming your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is not a trivial question. I hope it gets answered.